# How can I put a .2 in a <span>?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a cool counter on my website. It basically counts up to a certain number at a certain rate. I want it to go to 7.2 however it will only go to 7 probably because it is getting confused by the "." The code is below. Not sure of any fancy code for a period like   for a space. Thank You!

```
    <div class="col_one_fourth nobottommargin center col_last" data-animate="bounceIn" data-delay="600">
    <i class="i-plain i-xlarge divcenter nobottommargin icon-phone"></i>
    <div class="counter counter-lined"><span data-from="60" data-to="7.2" data-refresh-interval="30" data-speed="2700"></span></div>
    <h5>BILLION DEVICES! On Earth!</h5>
```

Java Script

```
counter: function(){

        if( !$().appear ) {
            console.log('counter: Appear not Defined.');
            return true;
        }

        if( !$().countTo ) {
            console.log('counter: countTo not Defined.');
            return true;
        }

        var $counterEl = $('.counter:not(.counter-instant)');
        if( $counterEl.length > 0 ){
            $counterEl.each(function(){
                var element = $(this);
                var counterElementComma = $(this).find('span').attr('data-comma');
                if( !counterElementComma ) { counterElementComma = false; } else { counterElementComma = true; }
                if( $body.hasClass('device-lg') || $body.hasClass('device-md') ){
                    element.appear( function(){
                        SEMICOLON.widget.runCounter( element, counterElementComma );
                        if( element.parents('.common-height') ) {
                            SEMICOLON.initialize.maxHeight();
                        }
                    },{accX: 0, accY: -120},'easeInCubic');
                } else {
                    SEMICOLON.widget.runCounter( element, counterElementComma );
                }
            });
        }
    },

    runCounter: function( counterElement,counterElementComma ){
        if( counterElementComma == true ) {
            counterElement.find('span').countTo({
                formatter: function (value, options) {
                    value = value.toFixed(options.decimals);
                    value = value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
                    return value;
                }
            });
        } else {
            counterElement.find('span').countTo();
        }
    },
```

Comment: I'm sure there's going to be some JavaScript that goes with this.

Comment: Is it converted to an 'int' and you need to specify it as a 'float'?

Comment: data-to should handle that just fine, its something else in your code causing a problem. put some more code so we can check.

Comment: I am not sure if there is any javascript. There is no reference to it. I think it is fully css. However I could and probably am wrong.

Comment: I added it. There are four other ones in a row and those worked fine it is just when I tried to use a period that it does not want to work

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle of some JS that I found. https://jsfiddle.net/sf2cLv11/

Comment: @Icewine Why cant I just tag someone

Comment: You should tag the person at the start of the comment, not make another comment later. However if you accidentally forget to tag the person you will simply have to add some extra text on the end of the comment (like you did there) to make it long enough to post. That's just the way the site works and it's to discourage comments like "+1" or "me too!" or "lol".

Comment: Well I thank you @Clonkex for that explination. I can sleep easy. Do you have any suggestions for my original issue? Hahaha. Thanks

Comment: @SethChouinard Nope, but lucky you, Paul just posted an answer that should help you figure this out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're still missing some code here, as there are clearly functions being added to things that you're not demonstrating.  Is there a jquery plugin or something you've installed?

You'll probably find what you're looking for by figuring out how that plugin configures the options it's passing to the formatter. Note:

```
formatter: function (value, options) {
           value = value.toFixed(options.decimals);
```

It's setting the value to a fixed decimal based on the `options.decimals`.  If that's either set to 0 or it's not set at all, you'll see the behavior you're observing, where it's setting 0 decimal places, which truncates 7.2 to 7.

**UPDATE**

OK, if you just add spaces and newlines to the fiddle in your comment it becomes pretty clear. There's a line that sets up the options object, and it pulls everything from the data attributes, e.g. `data-decimals='2'` would get passed to the params via `decimals:e(this).data("decimals")` and set the decimal places to 2 and your 7 would be 7.20.

Comment: Here is a JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/as0qh76x/ of the "countto" plugin I found. There is also a "countdown"

Comment: Unfortunately that is all gibberish to me however I noticed it says decimal many times.

Comment: Look at that. Working flawlessly. Thank you very much